# Ошибка Segmentation faul (core dumped)

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть код на C++ нужно посчитать сумму строк и столбцов по отдельности
.При создании и заполнении массива n * n все работает как только массив создать n*m  то выдает ошибку

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  int n, s, m;
  cin >> n >> m;
  int **arr = new int *[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      sum += arr[i][j];
    }
      cout << sum << " ";
    }
  cout << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
      sum += arr[i][j];
    }
      cout << sum << " ";
    }
  cout << endl << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
      cout << endl;
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      delete[] arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int **arr = new int *[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }
```

это не матрица NxM

прямоугольная матрица создаётся так:

```
  int **arr = new int *[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = new int[m];
    }
```

в вашем случае вы создавали матрицу у которой `n` строк кол-во столбцов равных номеру строки, в результате очень легко уходили за диапазон, когда вызывали `[i][j]`, где `j` было больше `i`

А вот вторая ошибка:

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
         sum += arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << sum << " ";
}
```

теперь вы обходите `i < m`, но если `m > n`, то обращаясь к arr[i][j] опять выходите за диапазон

Comment: Спасибо поменял, начал вводить значения, говорит опять что core dumped

Comment: @Марк Аржановский, добавил в мой ответ  описание еще одной ошибки - вы `m` с `n` перепутали похоже и опять вышли за диапазон

Comment: спасибо, все работает